# How to properly set start/end params of statsmodels.tsa.ar_model.AR.predict function

Tags: python, pandas, statsmodels

I have a dataframe of project costs from an irregularly spaced time series that I would like to try to apply the [`statsmodel` AR model against](http://www.statsmodels.org/stable/generated/statsmodels.tsa.ar_model.AR.html#statsmodels.tsa.ar_model.AR).

This is a sample of the data in it's dataframe:

```
               cost
date               
2015-07-16    35.98
2015-08-11    25.00
2015-08-11    43.94
2015-08-13    26.25
2015-08-18    15.38
2015-08-24    77.72
2015-09-09    40.00
2015-09-09    20.00
2015-09-09    65.00
2015-09-23    70.50
2015-09-29    59.00
2015-11-03    19.25
2015-11-04    19.97
2015-11-10    26.25
2015-11-12    19.97
2015-11-12    23.97
2015-11-12    21.88
2015-11-23    23.50
2015-11-23    33.75
2015-11-23    22.70
2015-11-23    33.75
2015-11-24    27.95
2015-11-24    27.95
2015-11-24    27.95
...
2017-03-31    21.93
2017-04-06    22.45
2017-04-06    26.85
2017-04-12    60.40
2017-04-12    37.00
2017-04-12    20.00
2017-04-12    66.00
2017-04-12    60.00
2017-04-13    41.95
2017-04-13    25.97
2017-04-13    29.48
2017-04-19    41.00
2017-04-19    58.00
2017-04-19    78.00
2017-04-19    12.00
2017-04-24    51.05
2017-04-26    21.88
2017-04-26    50.05
2017-04-28    21.00
2017-04-28    30.00
```

I am having a hard time understanding how to use `start` and `end` in the `predict` function.

According to [the docs](http://www.statsmodels.org/stable/generated/statsmodels.tsa.ar_model.AR.predict.html#statsmodels.tsa.ar_model.AR.predict):

> start : int, str, or datetime
>   Zero-indexed observation number at which to start forecasting, ie., the first > forecast is start. Can also be a date string to parse or a datetime type.
>
> end : int, str, or datetime Zero-indexed observation number at which
>   to end forecasting, ie., the first forecast is start. Can also be a
>   date string to parse or a datetime type.

I create a dataframe that has an empty daily time series, add my irregularly spaced time series data to it, and then try to apply the model.

```
data = pd.read_csv('data.csv', index_col=1, parse_dates=True)
df = pd.DataFrame(index=pd.date_range(start=datetime(2015, 1, 1), end=datetime(2017, 12, 31), freq='d'))
df = df.join(data)
df.cost.interpolate(inplace=True)
ar_model = sm.tsa.AR(df, missing='drop', freq='D')
ar_res = ar_model.fit(maxlag=9, method='mle', disp=-1)
pred = ar_res.predict(start='2016', end='2016')
```

The `predict` function results in an error of `pandas.tslib.OutOfBoundsDatetime: Out of bounds nanosecond timestamp: 605-12-31 00:00:00`

If I try to use a more specific date, I get the same type of error:

```
pred = ar_res.predict(start='2016-01-01', end='2016-06-01')
```

If I try to use integers, I get a different error:

```
pred = ar_res.predict(start=0, end=len(data))
Wrong number of items passed 202, placement implies 197
```

If I actually use a `datetime`, I get an error that reads `no rule for interpreting end`.

I am hitting a wall so hard here I am thinking there must be something I am missing.

Ultimately, I would like to use the model to get out-of-sample predictions (such as a prediction for next quarter).

Comment: ARMA assumes a standard time series data with equal spaced periods. Your dates are not unique and there is no clear frequency. One possibility would be to work without a time index (e.g. just a numpy array) and ignore the time spacing of the observations, or to aggregate/average them to a daily series.

Comment: This date and datetime handling has been refactored in statsmodels master and my guess is that it raises now an explicit exception in irregular cases like this. When you convert to nanosecond, then this might overflow somewhere when trying to create a time difference in nanoseconds that covers years.

Comment: "Your dates are not unique" - that was it - a groupby function was what I needed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I was creating a daily index to account for the equally spaced time series requirement, but it still remained non-unique (comment by @user333700).

I added a `groupby` function to sum duplicate dates together, and could then run the `predict` function using `datetime` objects (answer by @andy-hayden).

```
df = df.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper(freq='D')).sum()
...
ar_res.predict(start=min(df.index), end=datetime(2018,12,31))
```

With the `predict` function providing a result, I am now able to analyze the results and tweak the params to get something useful.

Answer (score 1):

This works if you pass a `datetime` (rather than a `date`):

```
from datetime import datetime

...
pred = ar_res.predict(start=datetime(2015, 1, 1), end=datetime(2017,12,31))

In [21]: pred.head(2)  # my dummy numbers from data
Out[21]:
2015-01-01   35
2015-01-02   23
Freq: D, dtype: float64

In [22]: pred.tail(2)
Out[22]:
2017-12-30   44
2017-12-31   44
Freq: D, dtype: float64
```

Comment: This gives me an error of `year is out of range`. If I try a smaller range `ar_res.predict(start=datetime(2016, 1, 1), end=datetime(2016, 6, 1))`, I still get this `out of bounds nanosecond timestamp` error. This also happens if I also update the pd.date_range to also use `datetime` instead of `date`. Will update my code above

Comment: If you provide a `data` hopefully we can replicate that.

Comment: added sample of `data` and how I generate its `pd.dataframe`

Comment: @getglad Still works for me, pandas 0.19.2 and statsmodels 0.8.0, python 3.6.1.