# How to properly set start/end params of statsmodels.predict function

Tags: python, statsmodels

I am doing a forecasting:

```
# Import the ARIMA module from statsmodels
from statsmodels.tsa.arima_model import ARIMA

# Forecast interest rates using an AR(1) model
mod = ARIMA(data, order=(1,1,1))
res = mod.fit()

# Plot the original series and the forecasted series
res.plot_predict(start='2014-07-02', end='2018-09-28')
plt.show()
```

I got an error:

```
KeyError: "invalid literal for int() with base 10: '2014-07-02'"
```

after reading statsmodels document: https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.tsa.arima_model.ARIMAResults.plot_predict.html
Then, the intuitive way is to check the type of '2014-07-02', it is pandas.core.indexes.datetimes.DatetimeIndex.
Thus, according to the document, datetime should be allowed. that's why I am confusing.

I followed Martijn Pieters's comment that the material question here is the index, the model doesn't have full dates as key, as it is Australian stock index:

```
            All Ordinaries closing price
Date    
2014-06-30  5382.0
2014-07-01  5366.5
2014-07-02  5441.7
2014-07-03  5479.5
2014-07-04  5511.8
2014-07-07  5506.3
2014-07-08  5498.5
2014-07-09  5442.2
2014-07-10  5454.3
2014-07-11  5474.6
```

Thus, some dates differ one day, some dates differ three days. However, I still don't understand why I cannot use res.plot_predict directly. Some others may have the same problem, as If I use a continuous time series, then it works.

Kriss provides a link under the comment, then I read it throughly, but I failed to use it to solve my problem:
In my data, every date is unique, but to make sure this point, I followed the answer:

```
data = data.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper(freq='D')).sum()


# Import the ARIMA module from statsmodels
from statsmodels.tsa.arima_model import ARIMA
from datetime import datetime


# Forecast interest rates using an AR(1) model
mod = ARIMA(data, order=(1,1,1))
res = mod.fit()

# Plot the original series and the forecasted series
res.plot_predict(start=min(data.index), end=datetime(2018,9,28))
plt.show()
```

Then, I have the same feeling that I want to hit the wall,I got the error:

```
KeyError: Timestamp('2014-06-30 00:00:00')
```

Comment: The example only has a *year* for the start and end. `int('2009')` works, `int('2014-07-02')` does not.

Comment: I found more hints in the [source code](https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/blob/master/statsmodels/tsa/base/tsa_model.py#L455-L465), *Depending on the underlying model's index, may be an integer, a date (string, datetime object, pd.Timestamp, or pd.Period object), or some other object in the
 model's row labels.* That's why you get a `KeyError`; the model doesn't have full dates as a key, it's some kind of integer-based column.

Comment: What exactly is `chg_data`? What index does that have? That's the material question here, because it is that input that determines what row labels you have.

Comment: Isn't it a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43835540/how-to-properly-set-start-end-params-of-statsmodels-tsa-ar-model-ar-predict-func

Comment: yes, this is a good solution, when I try to delete my question, I failed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem can be solved by using:

```
# Plot the original series and the forecasted series
res.plot_predict(start=datetime(2014,7,1), end=datetime(2018,9,28))
plt.show()
```

I can't use the first date, as I used first difference

Answer (score -1):

You're trying to convert a hyphen (-) to an integer, which is an impossible task with int()

Comment: The OP is not. The project they are using may be, but this doesn't tell them anything about what would be a correct argument.